# CSS - target a div using model info, razor

Tags: css, razor

Is there a way to inject model information into css? I have a model declared and I want to use that model info to target a specific div with an id of @Model.DataId-background. Is there any way to do this?

```
@Model deceleration

<style>
    #@Model.DataId-background { background-color: yellow; }
</style>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that visual studio will most likely give you build errors if you try something like this since it cannot be validated as html or a c#. You can however dynamically build up a piece of javascript to add your custom css style for you

Comment: @HanoJohannesRossouw yeah that was kind of my thought as well, just wanted to see if there was a workaround. Thanks.

Comment: One thing you can possibly do as well but will be a bit much if you only want to add your one style. You can form all your stylesheets into a single file , basically on a request it combines the text of all your css files and sends them as one and then you can add custom styles to you combined css string file, then on the top of your web page you can add only reference to your service or controller that sends back your string with mime type text/css